# How to migrate SVN to new server in phased approach

Tags: svn, live-migration

I'm currently migrating my dev services (VCS, CI, CD etc) to a new environment; part of this involves moving our SVN server. I've been able to set up the new SVN server (CollabNet Subversion) and copy over the existing repository using the `svnadmin` tool to `dump` from the source and `load` on the target. However, until we have finished migrating over the rest of the services (in this case, JIRA, Fisheye, TeamCity and Octopus Deploy), we don't want our developers to use the new server.

Now, I can continue to run the `svnadmin` tool one or two times a day to pick up incremental commits, but if this migration takes a couple of weeks to do, I would much rather automate the whole thing. I've seen plenty of articles on using `svnsync` to create a mirror, but I haven't seen anything on how to eventually break that sync and go with the new server. Is it a simple step?

Comment: Why not just run svnadmin periodically via cron?

Comment: `svnsync synchronize` in post-commit hook in SRC repo? And just start to use DST repo when it needed?

Comment: @EEAA it's probably down to me not being able to work out the previously exported revision for the incremental parameter

Comment: @LazyBadger sounds too easy...